# How do I correctly import models in Python if I'm having such directories?

Tags: python, django-models, python-import

I'm using Django-REST framework with a telegram-bot in here. I need to `import models`  from Django inside my telegram-bot file. I'm getting module not found error and probably thinking something wrong. Telegram-bot file is **commands.py** and the django models is **models.py**. The whole project looks like this:

[Project directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKZ6w.png)

I just want to properly `import models` inside my **commands.py** file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible solution for your question..
add following code inside my **commands.py** file

```
import sys
from django.apps import apps

from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(INSTALLED_APPS=['app_name'])

apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

from app_name.models import YourModel
```

also you may need to update path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/your/django/project')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, You are using Django REST Framework, so you should try with a serializer file. import your model in serializer file, because the syntax is correct 'from app_name.models import YourModel'.  Moreover, instead of  settings.configure(INSTALLED_APPS=['app_name'])  try this in settings.py
file in INSTALLED_APPS = 'app_name.apps.AppNameConfig'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).